# Sticky left cell in flexbox table on 'category' change

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

I have a list of items that I am presenting in a flexbox table.  My actual display has more columns, but in this question, I'll use just 2 - the 'category' and 'item' names.  The data is presented in category order.  Where items repeat for a category, only the first item for the category should have the category listed, for subsequent ones I want the category cell empty.  As this can scroll off the top of the screen, I'd like to make this cell sticky, as I do for the headings.

However, as the cell is a child of the row, not the container of the table, it scrolls up with the row.  You can see this in the first table in the example below, the '.first_item' CSS class does not hold the caption in place.

I concluded that the only way to achieve this is to insert a div before the row to present the category and make this sticky - class cat_head in the 2nd table in the example below.  This works, however, it knocks the first item down and does not align where I want it to.  I therefore set its height to 0px, which brings the item row back into alignment, but then have to put the text within an absolute positioned div within this so that I can set a background colour to stop text for the categories from overlaying each other.

It works really well and is exactly how I'd like it to operate - except that because the height is set to 0px, the absolute div extends below the bottom of the table as it is scrolled off the top of the screen and overwrites what is below it - you can see in the example it overwrites "Text below".

I also have to manually add an 'alt' class name on alternate rows to get background colouring rather than relying on ':nth-child(even)' - but I can live with this.

Has anyone got any suggestions for stopping it falling out of the bottom of the container, or indeed a better way of doing this?  Thanks.

```css
.pad {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.fill {
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.head {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 24px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cell {
 flex: 0 0 100px;
 padding: 5px;
}

.first_item {
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.table_1 .row:nth-child(even),
.table_2 .alt {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.cat_head {
  position: sticky;
  top: 25px;
  height:0px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cat_text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(8,156,213,1);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:2px 0 0 4px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="pad"></div>
  <div class="container table_1">
    <div class="row head">
      <div class="cell">Category</div>
      <div class="cell">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cat">
      <div class="cell first_item">Category 1</div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row cat">
      <div class="cell first_item">Category 2</div>
      <div class="cell">Item 2-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 2-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pad">Text below</div>

  <div class="container table_2">
    <div class="row head">
      <div class="cell">Category</div>
      <div class="cell">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_head">
      <div class="cat_text">Category 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row alt">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row alt">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 1-3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat_head">
      <div class="cat_text">Category 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 2-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row alt">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">Item 2-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fill">Text below</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK.  So I went to sleep on it and realised that the sticky positioning when scrolling off the top of the viewport is based on the bottom of its div.  Therefore, I need to shift the div below the row it is on - as its 0px high and that's where its 'bottom' should be.

I also need to move the contained absolute div above it rather than below so its bottom aligns to it.  I initially put a -24px top margin on the absolute div, but this stopped the sticky positioning on its parent for some reason.  I therefore put a -24px top margin on the sticky div, which worked.  However, it also dragged the next row up, so I also added a 24px bottom margin which resolved that.

I also added a containing div around each category's rows so that the sticky heading scrolls off screen when the next category gets to the top.

All working fine.

```css
.pad {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.fill {
  height: 120vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.head {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 24px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.cell {
 flex: 0 0 100px;
 padding: 5px;
}

.alt {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.cat_head {
  position: sticky;
  top: 27px;
  height:0px;
  margin: -24px 0 24px 4px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cat_text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(8,156,213,1);
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="pad"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row head">
      <div class="cell">Category</div>
      <div class="cell">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="row alt">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">Item 1-1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cat_head">
        <div class="cat_text">Category 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">Item 1-2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row alt">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">Item 1-3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">Item 2-1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="cat_head">
        <div class="cat_text">Category 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row alt">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell">Item 2-2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fill">Text below</div>
```